# "BorrowMutError" using the Interior Mutability Pattern

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I am trying to use the Interior Mutability Pattern to share mutable reference.

However, when I try to use the reference from the structs it is shared with, the program panics with the error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError'
```

Here is the code:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let game = Game::init();
    game.start();
}

struct Game {
    ecs: Rc<RefCell<Ecs>>,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn init() -> Game {
        let ecs = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Ecs::new()));
        ecs.borrow_mut().register_systems(vec![
            Box::new(Renderer {
                ecs: Rc::clone(&ecs),
            }),
        ]);
        Game {
            ecs: Rc::clone(&ecs),
        }
    }

    pub fn start(&self) {
        self.ecs.borrow_mut().update();
    }
}

struct Ecs {
    systems: Vec<Box<dyn System>>,
}

impl Ecs {
    fn new() -> Ecs {
        Ecs {
            systems: vec![],
        }
    }

    fn register_systems(&mut self, systems: Vec<Box<dyn System>>) {
        self.systems = systems;
    }

    fn update(&self) {
        for system in self.systems.iter() {
            system.update();
        }
    }

    fn test(&self) {
        println!("done!");
    }
}

trait System {
    fn update(&self);
}


struct Renderer {
    ecs: Rc<RefCell<Ecs>>,
}

impl System for Renderer {
    fn update(&self) {
        self.ecs.borrow_mut().test();
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be at the line:

```rust
self.ecs.borrow_mut().test();
```

What's the problem here? Is it related to the trait? Or do I need to call the function `test` in anoher way?

Comment: The message seems exactly correct: you are `borrow_mut()`ing the same `RefCell` twice (via two different `Rc` pointers to it), which is precisely what you must not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the `ecs` member in `Renderer` is a clone of the `ecs` member
in `Game`, i.e. they *both own* the same `Ecs`.

When you `borrow_mut()` the `ecs` member in `Game` then iterate on
the elements, you reach the `Renderer` which `borrow_mut()`s the
same `Ecs`.
This is detected at runtime and then panics, which the intended
behaviour of `RefCell`.

If you just change `borrow_mut()` to `borrow()` in both cases,
this does not panic any more since multiple immutable borrows
are allowed.

I don't know exactly the purpose of this code but I'm not certain
that borrowing the `Ecs` as whole from `Renderer` is a good idea.
I would presume that the interior-mutability should apply to each
stored component individually rather than to the whole `Ecs`.